# No project modules assigned to enterprise project

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, enterprise

I'm asking and answering my own question here, as I burned two days on this issue and there aren't any answers on the web since 2007 for this problem.

I was migrating an enterprise project from Eclipse Blue 2010 to Eclipse Blue 2016, when after correcting for build path changes, I started getting an error in the Problems View for the EARs:

> No project modules assigned to enterprise project

Using the

> ContextMenu > MyEclipse > Add and Remove Modules...

menu, everything matched the configurations of the other members of my team.
The facets matched, and the

> ContextMenu > MyEclipse > Add and Remove Project Deployments...

also matched.

See below for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the project migration did not properly relink the URI's to their projects in the workspace.

1. In the META-INF directory of the EAR, open the application.xml file.
2. In the Design View, there is an Outline on the left, you will see a topic called Modules, select it.
3. For each module in the list, double-click and choose the
   project in your workspace that contains the jar or war file named in the URI column.
4. Rebuild the workspace.